# Redirecting and Changing URL path (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is question has been asked but the answers were not clear. I have 2 directories in my root folder www.mysite.com/old & www.mysite.com/new

I would like to redirect all the http requests to www.mysite.com/new but I do not want the URL  to display /new/

I did manage to do it by creating an .htaccess file in the root directory with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)new
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new/$1 [L]
```

However the redirect works and it takes away the /new/ directory but when I click on a link the URL path changes back to www.mysite.com/new/mypage.php

The /new/ directory contains a WordPress site if that might be the problem, however there are no other .htaccess files in any other directory only in the root.

I would appreciate any advice a lot.

Thank you

Comment: Cant you use a simple `RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Why would you want to create this duplication i.e. same link can be accessed in 2 ways: `/new/abc` and `/old/abc`